# Срабатывание триггера

Tags: sql-server, sql

Почему если написать триггер на удаление таблицы T1

Таблица T1

```
id  id_employeeFrom id_employeeTo   
1          1              2
1          1              3
1          2              4    
1          3              5   
1          4              10  
1          10             11
```

Триггер на таблицу T1

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TR_MyTrigger] 
   ON  T1
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @id BIGINT

  SELECT TOP 1 @id = id
    FROM DELETED

  DELETE FROM T1
        WHERE     T1.id = @id
              AND T1.id_employeeFrom IN (SELECT id_employeeTo FROM DELETED)

END
```

запрос

```
DELETE FROM T1
      WHERE      id = 1 
`           `AND id_employeeTo = 2
```

триггер срабатывает только один раз, то есть в таблице остаётся:

```
id  id_employeeFrom id_employeeTo   
1          1              3
1          3              5   
1          4              10  
1          10             11
```

а мне нужно чтобы осталось

```
id  id_employeeFrom id_employeeTo   
1          1              3
1          3              5
```

Почему происходит так?
В общем, у меня не получается вытащить записи по иерархии, начиная с `id_employeeTo`...

Comment: А почему должно быть иначе, если в операторе удаления используется предикат:

id_employeeTo = 2

?

Comment: Там триггер на таблице есть, я думал, что он будет работать, как я планировал, а оказывается нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Триггер на операции, вызванные триггером, не срабатывает. Пишите в триггере рекурсивный запрос.

И вы не обрабатываете ситуацию, когда удаляется несколько записей с разными id, что плохо.

Как то так:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TR_MyTrigger] 
       ON  T1
       AFTER DELETE
    AS 
    BEGIN

    with t as
    (select t1.id, t1.id_employeeFrom, t1.id_employeeTo 
       from T1
            inner join DELETED d
                    on T1.id_employeeFrom = d.id_employeeTo
                   and T1.id = d.id
     union all
     select t1.id, t1.id_employeeFrom, t1.id_employeeTo
       from T1
            inner join t
                    on t1.id_employeeFrom = t.id_employeeTo
                  and T1.ID = T.ID)
delete from T1
from T1
     inner join t
             on t.id = t1.id
            and t1.id_employeeFrom = t.id_employeeFrom

delete from T1
from T1
     inner join deleted
             on T1.ID = DELETED.ID
            and T1.id_employeeTo = deleted.id_EmployeeFrom

END
```

Comment: я извеняюсь а кто нибудь может помочь написать такой запрос что то ни как не получается....?

Comment: Дописал в комментарий.

Comment: Я бы хотел уточнить, там, где (with t as) каждый раз при найденной записи он по циклу ищет новые, да?

Comment: with t as и дальше - это рекурсивный запрос, идет по дереву вниз, пока есть хотя бы одна запись, подчиняющаяся уже найденным. В MS SQL есть ограничение - не больше 100 итераций в рекурсии по умолчанию, если дерево глубже, будет падать.
Можно сказать, что в цикле, да, пока есть дочерние записи.

Comment: OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100); это да опция?

Comment: Да, эта. Если надо увеличить, можно поменять количество.

Comment: Почему не срабатывает? это регулируется параметром nested triggers в настройках сервера